# Quora Simple API & Cross Domain Origin Error?

Tags: javascript, jquery, api, cross-domain

I'm playing around with Quora's API.

I found this github repository for a quora browser extension [https://github.com/drusepth/Quora-Chrome-Extension/blob/master/stable/background.html], and it seems as easy as doing a GET of http://api.quora.com/api/logged_in_user?fields=notifs,inbox. And that should return the relevant JSON.

But when I try the same code from a local web page, I get this:

```
Origin http://localhost:8080 is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.
```

Why does this happen? And how can I work around it?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the api.quora.com domain to the permissions section of your manifest.json file. See here for more details: http://monsur.hossa.in/2011/07/07/chrome-extensions-and-cross-domain-requests.html